# How to import class into existing Java project, with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, class

I downloaded the svgsalamander.jar, with all its pretty classes and stuff. But i can not sucesfully load them into my existing Java project, using Eclipse, so, how can i do it?

I am truly sorry about asking this, but i tried with google, stack and found nothing useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project; select `Properties`.

Select `Java Build Path`.

Select the `Libraries` tab.

Click the `Add External JARs` button.

Find the path to your `JAR` and add it.

Comment: I would recommend putting/copying the JAR file in the project itself. For more hints: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29 You may accidently delete or move the JAR file outside Eclipse and the project would then break.