# Questions on how to import google-api-translate-java.jar 

Tags: java, google-api, google-translate

I am now going to use the .jar file on http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/. However, after I download it, I tried to import it in my current project folder (in Eclipse)

the two import statements

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language; 
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
```

always get complained by the compiler saying couln't find such class

Could any one help on how to correctly import this .jar file into a project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [How to import class into existing Java project, with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360286/how-to-import-class-into-existing-java-project-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to your build path. Right-click on the project in Project View, select Build Path->Configure Build Path, then Libraries tab. Now, use one of available options there to add a JAR.

Use "Add JAR" if you copied the jar to your project folder or "Add External JARs" to add it by poiting to a path in filesystem. (Anyway, it is better to copy the jar to the project folder, in which you want to use the jar).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `google-api-translate-java-0.92.jar` file to your project `/WEB-INF/lib/` folder and refresh your project (right click on project and select "refresh").

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate API v1 is deprectaed and will shutdown soon.
You can use [Google Translate API v2 Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/). It has a core module that you can call from your Java code and also a command line interface module.

Answer (score 0):

Hy I have faced the same issue and fixed it

**Step1**: download google-translate-api jar file

**step2**: paste into your app library file

**step3**: Goto project structure > app > select dependencies  -> then add path of your jar file...

Enjoy now you can acess google api services